# Difference between build /clean & build in a c++ project in netbeans IDE,test and debug test

Tags: c++, build, xdebug

I was wondering about the difference between the build/clean&build in c++ project in netbeans ide sometimes code runs prfect at others it produces some error can anyone suggest what is the better way to know ehen to use build/clean & build.

Also if u could tell me brief about what is test and debug test that would help...

as when i just test my code it doesnot givethe required functionality and when i do the debug test i get the functionality to some extent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A build just compiles only the source files that need to be compiled & links them together to form a new binary.

A clean build deletes all binaries and recompiles all the source files again from scratch & further links them together to form a new binary.

Typically, to save time in re-compilation a utility called **[Makefiles](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/courses/programming/Makefiles/Makefiles.html)** is used, In the Makefiles you are allowed specify dependencies for source files which formulate the rules for compilation in case any some of the source files are modified. The first case only compiles and links the source files that need to be compiled as per rules in the Makefile.